# Xpath expression to get all data inside the <p>

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

I have this html:

```
<div class="et_pb_text_inner">
 <h3 style="text-align: center;"><i class="fal fa-ruler-combined"></i><br /> 1672 Square Feet</h3>
  <p style="text-align: center;">
    First Floor 1085 s.f.<br />
    Second Floor 587 s.f.<br />
    Porches 393 s.f.<br />
    Covered Parking 642 s.f.<br />
    Storage 187 s.f.<br />
    Under Roof 2894 s.f.
  </p>
</div>
```

My Xpath code is:

```
//div[@class='et_pb_text_inner']/p/text()
```

But it only gives me the text before the first break line.

```
First Floor 1085 s.f.
```

Is there a way to get all data **only** inside the paragraph elements? Is there a way to delimit that?

I would like to get a string like that:

```
First Floor 1085 s.f.<br />Second Floor 587 s.f.<br />Porches 393 s.f.<br />Covered Parking 642 s.f.<br />Storage 187 s.f.<br />Under Roof 2894 s.f.
```

So after that I will try to clean the data.

I'm a pretty newbie at xpath expressions.

Thank you in advance for any help. =) And sorry about my broken English. :P

My .py code is:

```
import requests
from lxml import html


resp = requests.get(
    url="https://tyreehouseplans.com/shop/house-plans/beach-house-plans/crew-cut-house-plan/",
    headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
)

tree = html.fromstring(html=resp.text)

title = tree.xpath("//div[@class='et_pb_module_inner']/h1/text()")[0]
dimensions = tree.xpath("//div[@class='et_pb_text_inner']/p/text()")[0]


print(title)
print(dimensions)
```

Comment: What tool are you using? beautifulsoup?

Comment: Maybe `//div[@class='et_pb_text_inner']/p/following::text()` will help. I am not sure

Comment: Using the `lxml` module, your xpath expression appears to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi Guy I'm using lxml... I have to scrape data from some pages like that (https://tyreehouseplans.com/shop/house-plans/beach-house-plans/crew-cut-house-plan/) from this website... Do you think BS4 is better?

Comment: @FranciscoSanchez How did you do it? post the code

Comment: @SapanZaveri It doensn't work =( but thanks bro!

Comment: Ok @Guy I don't know how to put the code here in the comments... let me see.

Comment: @FranciscoSanchez Use the edit button under your post, put the code in the question.

Comment: Ok @Guy I'll try

Comment: All right, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

`text()` return a text node, the `<p>` tag contains 6 such nodes, so you need to remove the index `[0]`. You also need to give more accurate `xpath` to remove unwanted results

```
dimensions = tree.xpath("//h3[contains(., '1672 Square Feet')]/following-sibling::p/text()")
```

Will give a list with 6 strings

```
['First Floor 1085 s.f.', '\nSecond Floor 587 s.f.', '\nPorches 393 s.f.', '\nCovered Parking 642 s.f.', '\nStorage 187 s.f.', '\nUnder Roof 2894 s.f.']
```

Comment: Hey @Guy Thanks a lot man! It gave me ideas to continue coding... Thank you =)